# Multithreaded/async request and wait till they are all done and then process the results

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

i have (want) to execute a search request to multiple sources.
Now i've done some multithreading in the past, but it was all fire and forget.

Now what i want to do, is to spin up 3 identical requests on 3 different objects, wait until they are all 'done' (and that gives me the first question: how do they say 'i'm done', and then collect all the data thet've sent me.

So in pseudo code i have this interface:

```
interface ISearch
    SearchResult SearchForContent(SearchCriteria criteria)
```

So in code i create the three search services:

```
ISearch s1 = new SearchLocal();
ISearch s2 = new SearchThere();
ISearch s3 = new SearchHere();
```

And then call `SearchForContent(SearchCriteria criteria)` on all three of them, in a multihreaded / async way

and the they all come back to me with their `SearchResult` and after they are ALL done, i process their `SearchResult`  objects.

I hope these lines of text kindof makes you get what is in my head :)

i'm working on a ASP.Net 3.5 C# project.

Comment: It's easiest to do this kind of thing with `Task` objects. They were introduced in .NET 4, but have been backported in the (unsupported, use-at-your-own-risk) [Rx library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx). Is using Rx an option, or do you need a purely .NET 3.5 solution?

Comment: No, sorry, i need a purely 3.5 solution.

Comment: Gahh only now reading comment about 3.5, I guess Tasks won't work for you then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `AutoResetEvent` and pass them to `WaitHandle.WaitAll()`

There is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx).

Basically:

1) You create an `AutoResetEvent` for each search and pass `false` to its constructor.

2) Create the threads and run search for each one and at the end, call `Set` on the `AutoResetEvent` in the **finally** block. *It is very important that calling `Set` is done inside the finally block otherwise `WaitAll()` will be waiting indefinitely.*

3) In the code right after you have spawned the threads, you call `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` and pass all those `AutoResetEvent` to it. This code will **wait** until all is finished.

Comment: I have updated. There is another example here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.autoresetevent(VS.95).aspx

Comment: @Aliostad, you'll have to modify your `ISearch` implementations to accept the `AutoResetEvents` (or whatever wait handle you choose) in their constructors. Additionally, you'll need to add a way to access the results asynchronously (e.g., `ISearch.SearchResults { get; }`).

Comment: @Jeff yes that is right with changing ISearch for accepting  AutoResetEvent. But I don't agree with the second part, search results will be used by the main thread after WaitAll() returns.

Comment: @Aliostad - the main thread needs a way to access the results.

Comment: @Jeff you are so right! I thought the interface already provides a property for accessing it afterwards but it is just one method.

Comment: @Aliostad: i can make a property for it, if that makes life easier?

Comment: @Aliostad, so i pass the created AutoResetEvent  objects to the Search classes and then call the Set on that AutoResetEvent object in the searchclass. And if i make a property in the searchclass which contains the searchresults, i can access that after the WaitHandle.WaitAll() is done waiting?

Comment: @Michel. Your interface needs to be designed to be called Asynchronously but passing AutoResetEvent will be ugly although propety is not. My recommendation is to have your ISearch as it is but create a separate class for handling it Async.

Comment: I was wondering, in this solution i wait for all three to end. Is it also possible to be informed when the first one is ready? So if one takes 1 second to perform the search request, and the other two take 50 seconds, that i already do some logic logic on the first load of search results while waiting for the two others searches?

Comment: No. That would require building the continuation task into the async operation itself.

Comment: Thanks, was getting greedy wasn't i?

Comment: Greedy is good! It is when we stop looking for better solutions is when we fail.

Answer (score 2):

Using tasks you could do a continuation like this:

```
        Task[] t = new Task[2];
        t[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });
        t[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); });

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(t, myTasks => { Console.WriteLine("All done!"); });
```

Comment: it's 3.5 indeed, but thanks for the code anyway, never know when i'll need it in a 4.0 project!

Answer (score 0):

Make an `IEnumerable<ISearch>`, and those items to it, and do `.AsParallel().ForAll(...)` on it.

***Edit***

ForAll won't return results, if you can change ISearch, give it a property for the results, then once the ForAll is done you can look at the results through the IEnumerable.

And yes, sorry, this is 4.0.

Comment: ForAll will not return the results.